# Python - How to make an IF statement dependant on the attempts a user takes?

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm creating a code where if the user guesses the number, they win. Now, if they guess the number within ONE attempt, I want "Wow! You've guessed the number at the first attempt!" to be printed. However, if the user takes MORE THAN ONE attempt to guess the number, I want "Welldone you have guessed the number!" to be displayed. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
import random
n=random.randint(1,50)
playing = True
while playing:
   guess=int(input("Guess the number!"))
   if guess == n:
       print("Wow! You've guessed the number at the first attempt!")
       playing = False
   elif guess == n:
       print("Welldone, you have guessed the number!")
```

Comment: Just have a variable `num_guesses` that you increment for each input, and check against that in the branch where the user gets the answer correct.

Comment: What do I define num_guesses as?

Comment: Define it as `0`, outside of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just have a new variable that tracks the number of times the user gets wrong and include that in your if/else statement. Something like

```
attempts = 1
```

outside your while loop. And then inside would be something like

```
if guess == n and attempts == 1:
    print "WOW"
    playing = False
elif guess == n and attempts > 1:
    print "Well done"
    playing = False
attempts += 1 # increment attempts variable bc they guessed wrong. Go back to while loop
```